# local server displays yajra laravel datatables correctly, remote server gives error 500

Tags: laravel, laravel-datatables

I am able to see my datatables on my local server, so I pushed the files to git, pulled them to my local server, and published the assets using `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=datatables`.

I have also cleared the cache, and tried the following:

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled

$ composer dump-autoload

$ php artisan optimize:clear
```

Still I get an error 500 when I try to see the datatables on the remote server.  Here is my laravel.log, which I'm hoping tells someone else what I am not understanding.

```
[2021-02-02 18:11:40] production.ERROR: Target class [App\DataTables\SewalongsDataTable] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\DataTables\\SewalongsDataTable] does not exist. at /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:832)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#1 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#2 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#3 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#4 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(79): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#5 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(48): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency()
#6 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(28): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies()
#7 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies()
#8 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#10 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(692): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#11 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#12 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#14 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#16 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#18 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#19 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#20 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#21 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#23 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#25 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(694): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#27 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(669): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#28 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#29 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#30 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#31 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#32 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#34 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#35 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#36 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#38 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#39 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#40 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#41 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#42 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#43 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#44 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#45 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#46 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#47 /var/www/sewyourown/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#48 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class App\\DataTables\\SewalongsDataTable does not exist at /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:830)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(830): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#1 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#2 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#3 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#4 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#5 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(79): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#6 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(48): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency()
#7 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php(28): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies()
#8 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies()
#9 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#10 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#11 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(692): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#12 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#15 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#17 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#19 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#21 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#22 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#23 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#24 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#26 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(694): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#28 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(669): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#29 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#30 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#31 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#32 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#33 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#34 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#35 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#36 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#37 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#38 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#39 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#40 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#41 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#42 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#43 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#44 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#45 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#46 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#47 /var/www/sewyourown/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#48 /var/www/sewyourown/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#49 {main}
"}
```

What do I need to do to get this to work on my remote server?  Please dumb it down for me.  I've done this on other sites, so I do not get what isn't working this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicate that the class `SewalongsDataTable` wasn't found. So, you might as well check in your `app.php` or `AppServiceProvider`, or if you already put it in your `Controllers` you might want to check it out.

Also, consider try checking the namespace of `SewalongsDataTable`. In my cases, it is usually between these three.

After you notice something wrong, and it still doesn't work, don't forget to try to use `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I'm using laravel 8, so I did not add the provider or alias to my app config file.  In my SewalongController.php file, I am using App\DataTables\SewalongsDataTable.  My namespace in the SewalongsDataTable.php file is App\DataTables.  What I don't get is that it works on my local machine, and all these files are the same and being pushed to the remote server, so why wouldn't they work there?

Comment: I figured it out!  For whatever reason, my SewalongsDataTable.php file was actually named SewalongsDatatable.php, but referenced in camel case.  Renamed and refactored and it's now showing also on the remote server.  THANK YOU!